# Finding a point where the derivatives do not vanish

Tags: differential-geometry, algebraic-geometry

Let $F(x_1, \ldots, x_n)$ be a polynomial with integer coefficients. Suppose I can find a non-singular solution to the equation $F(\mathbf{x})=0$ within $(0,1)^n$. I was wondering knowing only this information would it be possible to find  $\mathbf{z} \in (0,1)^n$ with $F(\mathbf{z})=0$ such that $\partial F/\partial x_i (\mathbf{z}) \not = 0$ for all $1 \leq i \leq n$ ? (or is there a relatively simple criterion I can put on $F$ so that this is true?)
Any comments or explanation is appreciated. Thank you very much.

Comment: Do you also want $z$ to be a solution? If so, it shouldn’t be hard to find a counterexample; if not, almost every point should work as long as $F$ is nonconstant in each variable, and $x$ doesn’t matter at all.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan Yes, I would like $\mathbf{z}$ to be a solution. That is fixed now. Thank you.

Comment: In that case take $F(x) = (2x - 1)^2$. (This may or may not work depending on what you mean by "non-singular solution.")

Comment: @QiaochuYuan By singular I meant that there exists at least one derivative that doesn't vanish at that point...